# Using select distinct with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I am not sure if what I want can be done but basically, I have a homework where I am supposed to come up with sql statements to filter through a database of a made up TCM company in any way. I wanted to filter branch to see which branch earns the most revenue.

but I am stuck here because I don't know how to filter it.

```
select distinct b.branch_ID, t.fees
from treatment t,branch b, appointment a, appointment_treatment at
where t.treatment_ID = at.treatment_ID
and at.appt_ID = a.appt_ID
and b.branch_ID = a.branch_ID
```

The result is like so.

branch revenue

```
BR001   30.00   
BR001   45.00   
BR001   75.00   
BR002   28.00   
BR002   40.00   
BR002   60.00   
BR003   28.00   
BR003   60.00   
BR004   28.00
```

However, what I want is:

branch (sum of) revenue for each branch

```
BR001   30.00   
BR002   45.00   
BR003   75.00   
BR004   28.00   
BR005   40.00
```

but I can't think of a way to make this work!

[image]

Comment: Don't undertand what you want. In the data you posted you are not making sum, seems like you are just assigning BR00x to the next revenue found in the table...

Comment: If BR001  has values of 30, 45, and 75, how are you ending up with 30?

Comment: do you know how to GROUP BY branch.id, and calculate the SUM of the fees?  If you can do that, you can the query the query to get the TOP 1 ORDER BY 'revenue' - have you been shown the comma syntax for joins in your learning, as a matter of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you problem correctly, you can use GROUP BY clause combined with SUM function to achieve what you want, like this:

```
select 
  b.branch_ID, sum(t.fees)
from 
  treatment t,branch b, appointment a, appointment_treatment at
where 
  t.treatment_ID = at.treatment_ID
  and at.appt_ID = a.appt_ID
  and b.branch_ID = a.branch_ID
group by
  b.branch_ID
```